# Facing error while using keras subclassing

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, transformer-model

I was training an image caption generator using tensorflow. I was using a transformer for captions. But getting error while calling train_step().

```
class Transformer(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, row_size, col_size,
               target_vocab_size, max_pos_encoding, rate=0.1):
    super(Transformer, self).__init__()
    self.encoder = Encoder(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, row_size, col_size, rate)
    self.decoder = Decoder(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, 
                           target_vocab_size, max_pos_encoding, rate)
    self.final_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(target_vocab_size)

    def call(self, inp, tar, training):
      # inp, tar = inputs
      look_ahead_mask=None
      enc_padding_mask=None
      dec_padding_mask= create_masks_decoder(tar)
      enc_output = self.encoder(inp, training, enc_padding_mask)
      dec_output, attention_weights = self.decoder(
          tar, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask)
      
      final_output = self.final_layer(dec_output) #(batch_size, tar_seq_len, targe_vocab_size)

      return final_output, attention_weights


@tf.function
def train_step(img_tensor, tar):
  tar_inp = tar[:, :-1]
  tar_real = tar[:, 1:]
  dec_mask = create_masks_decoder(tar_inp)
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions, _  = transformer(img_tensor, tar_inp, True)
    loss = loss_function(tar_real, predictions)

  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, transformer.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, transformer.trainable_variables))
  train_loss(loss)
  train_accuracy(tar_real, predictions)
```

I was getting Notimplemented Error

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-91-d60ab8d0c9a6> in <module>()
>       4   train_accuracy.reset_states()
>       5   for (batch, (img_tensor, tar)) in enumerate(dataset):
> ----> 6     train_step(img_tensor, tar)
>       7     if batch % 50 == 0:
>       8       print("Epoch {} Batch {} Loss {:.4f} Accuracy {:.4f}".format(
> 
> 1 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py
> in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)    1145           except
> Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except    1146             if
> hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
> -> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)    1148             else:    1149               raise
> 
> NotImplementedError: in user code:
> 
>     File "<ipython-input-88-5348883c569f>", line 7, in train_step  *
>         predictions, _  = transformer(img_tensor, tar_inp, True)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py",
> line 67, in error_handler  **
>         raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 475, in call
>         raise NotImplementedError('Unimplemented `tf.keras.Model.call()`: if you '
> 
>     NotImplementedError: Exception encountered when calling layer "transformer_1" (type Transformer).
>     
>     Unimplemented `tf.keras.Model.call()`: if you intend to create a `Model` with the Functional API, please provide `inputs` and `outputs`
> arguments. Otherwise, subclass `Model` with an overridden `call()`
> method.
>     
>     Call arguments received:
>       • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 64, 2048), dtype=float32)
>       • training=tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 30), dtype=int32)
>       • mask=True
```

I have searched in many places and found that most people were missing call functions inside Class, but I have implemented call() inside my transformer class, so I don't know what is going wrong..

tensorflow-version:2.8
python:3.7
google-colab

Comment: I was referring to this article https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/01/implementation-of-attention-mechanism-for-caption-generation-on-transformers-using-tensorflow/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `call` method in [Keras](https://keras.io/api/models/model/) accepts just one positional argument. Ie. you should change your code to

```
  def call(self, inputs, training):
      inp, tar = inputs
```

You can see in the error that Keras received a tensor `tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 30), dtype=int32)` instead of a Boolean for the training optional parameter.